# Replacing Excel numeric cells values in a large range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to open an excel file and replace all cells with numerical values with an "x".

[image: enter link description here]

That is, the 1..9 of model_abc in the different weeks should be replaced with "x", same with 11, 14, 17 of model_123, etc. The empty cells should be left alone.

Note that there are hidden rows and columns that I would also like execute this replacement.

I wrote the following and it seems to work but takes a more than 10 minutes to go through the whole sheet. The XFD200 end range was arbitrarily picked to allow for expansion--a column will be added every week and some rows may be added in the future.

```
Sub RemoveCellValues(excel_filename As String)

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim excelWkBk As Excel.Workbook

    Set xlApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        Set excelWkBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excel_filename)
        With excelWkBk         

            Dim rng As Range
            Dim r   As Range

            Set rng = .Worksheets(1).Range("A3:XFD200")
            For Each r In rng
                If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
                    If IsNumeric(r.Value) Then
                        Debug.Print "Cell value " & r.Value & " " & r.Row & " " & r.Column
                        r.Value = "x"
                    End If
                End If
            Next r            

            .Save
            .Close
        End With
    End With

    '' quit excel application
    xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

As you can probably tell, this is my first foray with VBA and Excel. Is there a better way to do this? Can it be sped up while keeping the flexibility of keeping up with future expansions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numeric values are typed data and not the result of formulas, then no looping is needed:

```
Sub TheXFactor()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A3:XFD200").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    r.Value = "x"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like the column and rows with "Total" are formulas. I'm getting this error with your suggestion: `Unable to get the SpecialCells property of Range class`. Is this because of the formulas?

Comment: I had a typo copying your code over. It works now and is really fast. Thanks!